# How can I remove a content block during install of a module, specifically a bluefoot block?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, third-party-module

I am trying to overwrite the following Bluefoot content block found in `vendor/gene/bluefoot/model/setup/data/pagebuilder_blocks_core.json`

```
{
  "identifier": "button_item",
  "name": "Button",
  "content_type": "block",
  "description": "Single Button",
  "url_key_prefix": null,
  "preview_field": "link_text",
  "renderer": "core_default",
  "item_view_template": "core_button_item",
  "list_template": null,
  "list_item_template": null,
  "item_layout_update_xml": null,
  "list_layout_update_xml": null,
  "singular_name": "Button",
  "plural_name": null,
  "include_in_sitemap": "0",
  "searchable": "0",
  "icon_class": "fa fa-mouse-pointer",
  "color": "#5284bd",
  "show_in_page_builder": "0",
  "sort_order": "0",
  "group": "general",
  "attribute_data": {
    "attributes": [
      "link_text",
      "link_url",
      "css_classes"
    ],
    "groups": [
      {
        "attribute_group_name": "General",
        "sort_order": "1",
        "default_id": "0",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attribute_code": "link_text",
            "sort_order": "1"
          },
          {
            "attribute_code": "link_url",
            "sort_order": "2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "attribute_group_name": "Advanced",
        "sort_order": "2",
        "default_id": "0",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attribute_code": "css_classes",
            "sort_order": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the new json I am trying to add to the DB during install of my module.

```
{
"content_blocks": [
  {
    "identifier": "button_item",
    "name": "Button",
    "content_type": "block",
    "description": "Single Button",
    "url_key_prefix": null,
    "preview_field": "link_text",
    "renderer": "core_default",
    "item_view_template": "core_button_item",
    "list_template": null,
    "list_item_template": null,
    "item_layout_update_xml": null,
    "list_layout_update_xml": null,
    "singular_name": "Button",
    "plural_name": null,
    "include_in_sitemap": "0",
    "searchable": "0",
    "icon_class": "fa fa-mouse-pointer",
    "color": "#A55A55",
    "show_in_page_builder": "0",
    "sort_order": "0",
    "group": "general",
    "attribute_data": {
      "attributes": [
        "link_text",
        "link_url",
        "button_type",
        "css_classes"
      ],
      "groups": [
        {
          "c": "General",
          "sort_order": "1",
          "default_id": "0",
          "attributes": [
            {
              "attribute_code": "link_text",
              "sort_order": "1"
            },
            {
              "attribute_code": "link_url",
              "sort_order": "2"
            },
            {
              "attribute_code": "button_type",
              "sort_order": "3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "attribute_group_name": "Advanced",
          "sort_order": "2",
          "default_id": "0",
          "attributes": [
            {
              "attribute_code": "css_classes",
              "sort_order": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
],
"attributes": [
  {
    "attribute_code": "button_type",
    "attribute_model": null,
    "backend_model": null,
    "backend_type": "varchar",
    "backend_table": null,
    "frontend_model": null,
    "frontend_input": "select",
    "frontend_label": ["Button Type"],
    "frontend_class": null,
    "source_model": "eav\/entity_attribute_source_table",
    "is_required": "1",
    "is_user_defined": "1",
    "is_unique": "0",
    "note": null,
    "is_global": "0",
    "is_wysiwyg_enabled": "0",
    "is_visible": "1",
    "content_scope": "0",
    "frontend_input_renderer": null,
    "widget": null,
    "data_model": null,
    "template": null,
    "list_template": null,
    "additional_data": [],
    "entity_allowed_block_type": false,
    "option": {
      "value": {
        "option_0": ["primary"],
        "option_1": ["secondary"],
        "option_2": ["alt"],
        "option_3": ["action"]
      },
      "order": {
        "option_0": "",
        "option_1": "",
        "option_2": "",
        "option_3": ""
      },
      "delete": {
        "option_0": "",
        "option_1": "",
        "option_2": "",
        "option_3": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```

The new `button_type` is being inserted into the db correctly, but the json that I want to overwrite the `button_item` is not working.

I have this install script where I am installing this json file, and I believe I need to delete the old `button_item` content block from the DB first in order for the new one to work. Here is the install script.

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php    

<?php

namespace vendor\module\Setup;

use Gene\BlueFoot\Model\Attribute\ContentBlock as ContentBlock;
use Gene\BlueFoot\Model\Attribute\ContentBlockRepository;
use Gene\BlueFoot\Model\Installer\File as InstallerFile;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File as IoFile;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Class to install data for list builder BlueFoot block
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Reader
     */
    protected $moduleReader;

    /**
     * @var IoFile
     */
    protected $ioFile;

    /**
     * @var InstallerFile
     */
    protected $fileInstaller;

    /**
     * @var Bluefoot content block repository manager
     */
    protected $contentBlockRepository;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $attributeFactory;

    protected $contentBlockInterface;

    /**
     * InstallData constructor.
     *
     * @param Reader $moduleReader
     * @param IoFile $ioFile
     * @param InstallerFile $fileInstaller
     */
    public function __construct(
        Reader $moduleReader,
        IoFile $ioFile,
        InstallerFile $fileInstaller,
        ContentBlockRepository $contentBlockRepository
    ) {
        $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
        $this->ioFile = $ioFile;
        $this->fileInstaller = $fileInstaller;
        $this->contentBlockRepository = $contentBlockRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $buttonItemBlock = $this->contentBlockRepository->getByIdentifier('button_item');
        $this->contentBlockRepository->delete($buttonItemBlock);

        //Install the blocks and attributes
        $this->installData($setup);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * Install blocks and attributes from specified JSON file
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     */
    protected function installData(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        $file = $this->moduleReader->getModuleDir(false, 'Vendor_Module') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Setup' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'install-blocks-attributes.json';

        if ($this->ioFile->fileExists($file)) {
            $this->fileInstaller->install($file, $setup);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Gene\BlueFoot\Model\Attribute\ContentBlockRepository::delete() must be an instance of Gene\BlueFoot\Api\Data\ContentBlockInterface, instance of Gene\BlueFoot\Model\Attribute\ContentBlock\Interceptor given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by just adding the new attribute type and then adding it to the attribute set of the button_item.

Here is the install code.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Gene\BlueFoot\Setup\EntitySetupFactory;
use Gene\BlueFoot\Model\Installer\File as InstallerFile;
use Gene\BlueFoot\Model\Attribute\ContentBlockRepository;
use Gene\BlueFoot\Api\Data\EntityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File as IoFile;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Class to install data for list builder BlueFoot block
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Reader
     */
    protected $moduleReader;

    /**
     * @var IoFile
     */
    protected $ioFile;

    /**
     * @var InstallerFile
     */
    protected $fileInstaller;

    /**
     * @var ContentBlockRepository
     */
    protected $contentBlockRepository;

    /**
     * @var EntitySetupFactory
     */
    protected $entitiySetupFactory;

    /**
     * InstallData constructor.
     *
     * @param Reader $moduleReader
     * @param IoFile $ioFile
     * @param InstallerFile $fileInstaller
     */
    public function __construct(
        Reader $moduleReader,
        IoFile $ioFile,
        InstallerFile $fileInstaller,
        ContentBlockRepository $contentBlockRepository,
        EntitySetupFactory $entitySetupFactory
    ) { 
        $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
        $this->ioFile = $ioFile;
        $this->fileInstaller = $fileInstaller;
        $this->contentBlockRepository = $contentBlockRepository;
        $this->entitiySetupFactory = $entitySetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        //Install the new blocks and attributes
        $this->installData($setup);

        //Grab the block element button_item so that we know what group to add the button_type to
        $buttonItemBlock = $this->contentBlockRepository->getByIdentifier('button_item');
        $buttonItemBlockData = $buttonItemBlock->getData();

        //Create an eav setup object
        $eavSetup = $this->entitiySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        //Get the button_item group id
        $attrGroupID = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(EntityInterface::ENTITY, $buttonItemBlockData['attribute_set_id']);
        //Get the button_type information
        $eavAttr = $eavSetup->getAttribute(EntityInterface::ENTITY, 'button_type');
        //Add it to the button_item set
        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            $eavAttr['entity_type_id'],
            $buttonItemBlockData['attribute_set_id'],
            $attrGroupID,
            $eavAttr['attribute_id'],
            3
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * Install blocks and attributes from specified JSON file
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     */
    protected function installData(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        $file = $this->moduleReader->getModuleDir(false, 'Vendor_Module') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Setup' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'install-blocks-attributes.json';

        if ($this->ioFile->fileExists($file)) {
            $this->fileInstaller->install($file, $setup);
        }
    }
}
```

And my new config file

```
{
"attributes": [
  {
    "attribute_code": "button_type",
    "attribute_model": null,
    "backend_model": null,
    "backend_type": "varchar",
    "backend_table": null,
    "frontend_model": null,
    "frontend_input": "select",
    "frontend_label": ["Button Type"],
    "frontend_class": null,
    "source_model": "eav\/entity_attribute_source_table",
    "is_required": "1",
    "is_user_defined": "1",
    "is_unique": "0",
    "note": null,
    "is_global": "0",
    "is_wysiwyg_enabled": "0",
    "is_visible": "1",
    "content_scope": "0",
    "frontend_input_renderer": null,
    "widget": null,
    "data_model": null,
    "template": null,
    "list_template": null,
    "additional_data": [],
    "entity_allowed_block_type": false,
    "option": {
      "value": {
        "option_0": ["primary"],
        "option_1": ["secondary"],
        "option_2": ["alt"],
        "option_3": ["action"]
      },
      "order": {
        "option_0": "",
        "option_1": "",
        "option_2": "",
        "option_3": ""
      },
      "delete": {
        "option_0": "",
        "option_1": "",
        "option_2": "",
        "option_3": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```